# What is the Ubuntu equivalent to Windows' Disk Managment?

Tags: disk-management

Does Ubuntu come with an equivalent to the Disk Management tool in Windows? How do I access it?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [Disks utility](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-disk-utility/) which is installed by default.

Just search for *"Disks"* in the dash or run `gnome-disks` from terminal.

[image: starting disks from the dash]

It does look a bit different than Windows Disk Management, but includes a variety of features:

- Creating new partition tables
- Creating and restoring disk images (this is what `dd` does, just nicer and with a progress bar)
- Benchmarking disks or partitions
- Reading SMART data (for disks and data connections that support it)
- *Apply Standby Timeout Settings* and *Enable Write Cache*  (through *Drive Settings…* menu option)
- Manually putting drives into standby mode or shutting them down
- Format partitions
- Setting partition flags and attributes
- Changing partition labels
- Handling LUKS encrypted disks

…and probably a lot more. If you're just looking for a straight forward partition manager you may want to have a look at [GParted](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gparted/).

What you may not find in any graphical tool to my knowledge is how to create and manage software RAID arrays. You should have a look at [btrfs](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Using_Btrfs_with_Multiple_Devices), [ZFS](http://open-zfs.org/wiki/Main_Page) ([on Linux](https://pthree.org/2012/04/17/install-zfs-on-debian-gnulinux/)) and [mdadm](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/mdadm.8.html) for this functionality.

[image: showing context menus for drives and partitions]

Comment: One big advantage of Disks over GParted: LVM support. GParted can't see what's inside LVM, Disks shows it as a separate disk.

Answer (score 4):

The partitions manager in Ubuntu would be the [Disks](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-disk-utility/) utility.

In a terminal:

```
gnome-disks
```

In the launcher, search for *Disks*.

Answer (score 0):

GParted is also a very good utility for changing partitioning of disks round! Used to be installed by default, not sure if it still is, but definitely still in repositories :)

Comment: Not installed by default.

Comment: Installing it only takes one `sudo apt-get install gparted`. I personally prefer it to `gnome-disks`.